# Issue when using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have a tricky problem. In one of my app, with over 150.000 downloads... I have a problem which seldom occurs and which I can't seem to figure out.

The problem is the following: 
In a view where the user can share a list via email, I open the mail window using `MFMailComposeViewController`. However, in some few cases the app seems to get a problem using the mail composer. The user presses the share button, the mail windows slides up, waits about 1-2 sec and then closes again. No content in the mail window, although I do send data to it.
I myself have not been able to re-create the problem on any device or in the simulator, however one colleague has. 
I ran the app using XCode on his phone and got the following in the logs:

```
2013-03-01 14:43:39.604 appname[318:907] <MFMailComposeRemoteViewController: 0x1ebfb100> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService
2013-03-01 14:43:39.631 appname[318:907] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=XPCObjectsErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (XPCObjectsErrorDomain error 2.)"
```

I googled the error "timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService" but can't really find any help.

Does anybody have any experience with this? How can I solve it?

My code for opening the view:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheetWithBodyString:(NSString *)aBody
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setSubject:@"Lista"];

        NSString *emailBody = aBody;
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Din enhet är inte redo att skicka e-post. Kontrollera dina inställningar", nil)
                                   message:nil
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                         otherButtonTitles:nil]
         show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm experiencing the exact same problem you describe. A friend has this problem on an iPhone 4 but I cannot reproduce it on a iPod touch 4th gen, 3GS, 4S or a 5. I thought maybe it was due to the size of the attachment so also tried zipping it (was a csv), but no difference.

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same problem, November 2013.  Thank goodness, the workaround works  **use one global MFMailComposeViewController and only use that** .. then you are golden.  Identical question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298448/ios6-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-slow-to-load-and-flashes-black-screen-mailcom

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem. On iOS 6 the composer opens and then closes, on iOS 7 it works but is unresponsive for a couple of seconds. Looks like synchronisation bug by Apple.
When presenting MFMailComposeViewController in dispatch_after block (with minimal delay, say, 0.1 sec) it does not fail and is ready for user interaction almost instantly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if you have fixed the problem, but I have met it recently in my project.

A workaround I did was to **allocate and initiate MFMailComposeViewController in an earlier stage, and hold it in one static variable**, whenever it's needed, get the static MFMailComposeViewController instance and present it.

It seems working for me, hope it will work for you, too.

Comment: Furthermore, you will almost certainly have to "cycle" the global MFMailComposeViewController after each use.  It is not reliable to "re-use" the same one.  Have a global routine which release and then re-initializes the singleton MFMailComposeViewController. Call it each time after you are finished with it. What a hassle.

Comment: Hey guys, what if I use UIActivityViewController??

Answer (score 5):

a had the same issue, and this fixe helped me:

https://twitter.com/christian_beer/statuses/321295533077565440

"@nathangaskin well… that was long ago :) But if I remember correctly, it worked after I removed the custom fonts from my UIAppearance code"

It works fine for me.

Also, second option is to simply wrap displaying call into

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

block

Comment: I like that solution better than allocating the view controller statically & earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same issue. I think I have nailed it down to the time it takes to formulate the message body string.

***Content from comment***

```
 //Message Body 
NSString *msgBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"I noticed these results in pocketKPI. The %@ was at %@ which is a variance of %@(or %@) to the target defined as %@. When you have some time let's discuss.", 
                        self.itemToView.kpiName, 
                        [DFSKpiFormatter formatNumberAsString:self.itemToView.currentValue], [self.itemToView determineVarianceLabelText],
                        [self.itemToView determineVariancePercentLabelText], 
                        [DFSKpiFormatter formatNumberAsString:self.itemToView.targetValue]];
```

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. Do you formulate it dynamically?

Comment: Yes I do.
    
    //Message Body
    NSString *msgBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I noticed these results in pocketKPI. The %@ was at %@ which is a variance of %@(or %@) to the target defined as %@. When you have some time let's discuss.", self.itemToView.kpiName, [DFSKpiFormatter formatNumberAsString:self.itemToView.currentValue], [self.itemToView determineVarianceLabelText],[self.itemToView determineVariancePercentLabelText], [DFSKpiFormatter formatNumberAsString:self.itemToView.targetValue]];