# iOS 8 : MFMailComposeViewController Displays Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

when i run this in Xcode 6 ... it appears and automatically dismissed after few seconds with below mentioned error and also i can't able to edit the textfield (To/BCC/Subject)..

Error :  timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService.

My code........

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:@"Mail"];

    if(![share_link isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [mailViewController setMessageBody:share_link isHTML:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"http://www.google.com/" isHTML:NO];
    }
    return mailViewController;
```

Comment: Could this help you?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604552/i-have-real-misunderstanding-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-ios8-in

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159412/issue-when-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller