# MFMailComposeViewController tintColor not working on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an `MFMailComposeViewController` on an iPad version of my app that is acting up. I want the Cancel and Send buttons to be tinted `[UIColor whiteColor]`, so I have set `mailViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]`. This seemed to do the trick on the simulator, but when I run it on a device it shows up as dark gray text (which blends in with the bar's background and makes it impossible to read). Other things I have tried:

`[mailViewController.navigationBar layoutSubviews]` after it is presented.
`[mailViewController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay]` after it is presented.

And also doing both of the above for each subview of the navigationBar. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: one of 1000000 duplicates here. apple uses new remote view controllers

Comment: Sorry if it's a duplicate question but instead of just commenting to say it's a duplicate could you perhaps point me in the direction of a working solution? So far everything that I have found hasn't solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is no working solution. they mail VC isn't part of your app. that is the point of remote vcs. ergo they can't be customised.. or only in very limited way.

see [iOS6: MFMailComposeViewController slow to load and flashes black screen; MailCompositionS begins hogging memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298448/ios6-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-slow-to-load-and-flashes-black-screen-mailcom/13298642#13298642)